# A way to avoid wasting memory

Tags: c#, xna

At the moment, I've got a system in place where I record a gamepad state in a struct and store this in a list of states to record the input for the duration of a videogame.  The full state of the pad takes up 192bits per frame but this is a little wasteful. For example, if the analog triggers on the pad aren't being pressed they still take 32bits up, each, in storage.  So obviously I'm looking to save some space.

I had tried setting this to NULL but it appears to have no effect on the size of the binary file that the system saves at the end of the match.

What alternatives are available in a situation where you only need to record or save certain values but retain the integrity of a data structure?

EDIT:

I think I've found a solution; of sorts.  Earlier I tried setting values to NULL by overriding the standard float with System.Nullable in the struct.  My idea is that setting this to a NULL value in the struct will serialize much smaller. I'm under the impression that NULL is recorded as 4bits. It might be more, it probably is. Anyway, the code I had earlier had a rather glaringly obvious fault so I've gone back and fixed it again. Now I'm getting much much smaller replays and the accuracy seems to be just as good so I'm going to assume that the NULL trickery is doing something properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you do.

You use a bit stream to only write the bits of information that makes a difference. In the case where you have lots of sparse data you write out a bit mask before anything else, that tells you which of the following bits contain data.

This way, something like a vector can be reduced to just 3 zero bits. If the vector is empty/zero. If only one component of the vector is valid then that's 3 bits + only the size of that component. On top of this you can of course add compression, however, at some point the distribution of bits (when your being cleaver about it) becomes very even. This makes general purpose compression methods less optimal and they might even increase the size of your output instead.

And what you do is that you periodically write this stuff out to disk, so that you never keep a huge chuck of it in memory.

Comment: The problem I've had with writing periodically is that I'm saving a binary file. I can use the Append mode to write to the file but it doesn't play back properly; it stops at the point at which the first write occurs and plays nothing after that.  Also, I found that the appended file was huge.  This is still very much a work in progress; I'm just trying to iron out the kinks one at a time.

Comment: Something like replay functionality is tedious work, because the slighest mistakes messes everything else up. If your having problems with the stream and writing out things on disk, interleave your data stream with metadata and debug information, it will go a long way to help your detect problems. If your being very eager about what you put in that stream the amount of data will pile up very quicky, it's 60 FPS but do you need to run your game input loop at that speed too? Often a buffered input approach with a lower frequency yields just as good results but at less the cost.

Comment: The system I'm making at the moment is actually a proof of concept that I'm putting together for my Dissertation. The recording method I have at the minute works just fine but obviously there are improvements that could be made and discussed on the subject. Unfortunately, input recording for replays, from a game perspective at least, are few and far between and what I have found have been rather vague so I've been stabbing wildly in the dark.  I'll have a look reducing the speed of the game update; thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Not in a struct, I think. You may need a bit more complicated protocol.

For example (very rough and not thought through) (WHAT 3xough):

The first byte contains the state of 8 buttons, one bit for each button. If a bit for a button is set to 1 the client (I call it the client for now) expects more specific data for that button, like direction and such, in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to split your struct and/or use a compression.

But the major saving could be to save *during* the game, not all at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could store only deltas maybe? In many situations, that gives a nice compression.

For your bit type states, it doesn't change size, only meaning.

For your float types though, it reduces to 1 bit in most cases, and only increase by 1 bit in the other cases.